# crash report : java.lang.RuntimeException , Caused by: androidx.startup.StartupException , Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: java, kotlin, exception, crash, runtimeexception

i have this Crash details , could you help me ?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:8074)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:7605)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication (ActivityThread.java:7489)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:7446)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:301)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2148)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8512)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1139)
```

and

```
Caused by: androidx.startup.StartupException: 
  at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize (SourceFile:17)
  at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize (SourceFile:16)
  at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate (SourceFile:2)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:2429)
  at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:2399)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:8069)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:2385)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:2369)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2352)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2294)
  at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.requestNetwork (IConnectivityManager.java:4597)
  at android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork (ConnectivityManager.java:4194)
  at android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback (ConnectivityManager.java:4706)
  at android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback (ConnectivityManager.java:4673)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.a.b (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:19)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl.getMobileAdsSettingManager (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:5)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bs.bL (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:4)
  at fv.onTransact (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@211512000@211512000057.367949677.367949677:4)
  at android.os.Binder.transact (Binder.java:1079)
  at dwa.eN (com.google.android.gms@212418046@21.24.18 (150400-383468479):2)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.be.getMobileAdsSettingManager (com.google.android.gms@212418046@21.24.18 (150400-383468479))
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl.getMobileAdsSettingManager (com.google.android.gms@212418046@21.24.18 (150400-383468479):5)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bf.ei (com.google.android.gms@212418046@21.24.18 (150400-383468479):4)
  at dwb.onTransact (com.google.android.gms@212418046@21.24.18 (150400-383468479):11)
  at android.os.Binder.transact (Binder.java:1079)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzgw.zza (SourceFile:2)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyk.zzb (SourceFile:4)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzz.zzh (SourceFile:3)
  at fv0.d (SourceFile:3)
  at iv0.b (SourceFile:12)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzn.b (SourceFile:4)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzn.zza (SourceFile:11)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize (SourceFile:3)
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize (SourceFile:4)
  at com.ton.vpn.utils.AdUtils.initialize (SourceFile:1)
  at com.ton.vpn.Config.config (SourceFile:3)
  at com.ton.vpn.utils.framework.G$Companion.setConfig (SourceFile:2)
  at com.ton.vpn.utils.initializer.MainInitializer.create (SourceFile:3)
  at com.ton.vpn.utils.initializer.MainInitializer.create (SourceFile:1)
  at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize (SourceFile:14)
```

i saw this report in android 11 SDK 30 , And for my client
I personally did not encounter this crash.
don't know where to begin since I have never encountered this error or similar crash

Comment: could you provide code from your AnroidManifest, please?